# Installing Xorg without Gnome

Tags: xorg, 20.04

I use to set up my Ubuntu desktop from scratch, (Ubuntu server + Xorg + Openbox etc...).
But I found out that in the 20.04 lts version, Xorg comes with Gnome out of the box.
I tried `sudo apt install xorg-server` but I get an error:
`E: Unable to locate package xorg-server`

Is it still possible to install Xorg without installing Gnome ?

Comment: I'm having this very problem too. I need to have a minimal X server to launch Chromium in kiosk mode, but `xinit` hauls in all kind of Gnome stuff now. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is the dependencies, package suggestions and recommendations.

At first - there is no binary [`xorg-server`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xorg-server&searchon=names) package in the repositories, this is the name of source code package, so there are binary packages which [were built from it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/xorg-server).

So you have to install one of them with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests
```

To install [Openbox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openbox) with minimal dependencies use:

```
sudo apt-get install openbox --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests
```

For correct Xorg initialisation you have to install [`xinit` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xinit) by:

```
sudo apt-get install xinit
```

Finally you need to install the login manager like [Slim](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/slim) with:

```
sudo apt-get install slim
```

And then reboot or launch `slim` manually by `sudo service slim start`.

Notes:

1. The resulting system installed from [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) will contain about 500 packages.
2. If you want to have easy way and do not really care about 50 extra packages - use simple one command to install all the stuff - `sudo apt-get install xinit openbox slim` .

Comment: Thanks it works.
Actually the arguments `--no-install-recommends` and `--no-install-suggests` are not necessary.
But the ordering of the installs is important.

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core`
`sudo apt-get install openbox`
`sudo apt-get install xinit`

If I install `xinit` before `openbox` the Gnome package will be installed as well.

Comment: I saw the same, this is why answer was edited 5 times :) So you can accept my answer.

Comment: I think that `--no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests` would be required as "standard" in anything to do with applications that have a graphical component. I just did a minimal installation, came up exactly to the same thing described here but even trying to install `terminator` went ahead and installed gnome.....for...reasons...

Comment: can anyone confirm that those packages are enough for x11 authentication via ssh -X? My $DISPLAY is localhost:10.0, when running a GUI application (qt-based) I get: `qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:10.0`

Comment: I use Motif Window Manager and I can confirm the order matters. If you install xinit before installing a window manager, you get the entire Gnome landslide!