# Is there anything more minimal that Ubuntu minimal(mini.so)?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I just finished installing Ubuntu minimal(mini.iso) downloaded from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/).

After running **apt-mark showmanual** I notice that alot of packages come with the mini.iso ...

Is there something more minimal ?

Comment: Yes: [Ubuntu Base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base). Enjoy.

Comment: It might help if you explain exactly what you're after. You can view the package *depends* rules online (https://packages.ubuntu.com/), but it doesn't take any effort to remove unwanted/unneeded packages.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1256290/66509 as example of `--no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests` usage.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not Ubuntu, but search up "damn simple linux" all it is, is just linux at the core with no package manager and a few built in apps.