# Why does latest ubtunu base installs some unwanted packages by default?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to install latest ubuntu 20.04 base with openbox and lightdm. I did 14.04 which worked perfectly. But on 20.04 everytime apt automatically installs ubuntu desktop environment and both gdm3 and lightdm. Why is that happending and is there any way to turn this off?

These are what i did:

- prep base rootfs and chroot
- cp resolv.conf
- ```
  apt install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic lightdm openbox obconf  xterm backport-iwlwifi-dkms git nano
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Xorg without Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256285/installing-xorg-without-gnome) as adjusting `--no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests` seems to be your way.

Comment: now i feel stupid++ xD

Comment: I found xorg core a better solution