# Ubuntu 20.04 Install minimal xorg with lightdm

Tags: 20.04, xorg, lightdm

I am trying to install a minimal 20.04 (bento vagrant based), with lightdm installed. When I try to install lightdm, gdm3 is also installed and preferred along with wayland.

Is there an actual recipe to install the minimal xwindows/xorg with lightdm only?

What I am trying to use (because I'll be doing an ansible script later):

Upon upping the vagrant bento/ubuntu20.04 (vanilla no stuff changed):

`$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`
`$ sudo apt install lightdm`

If you run `apt install lightdm --dry-run|grep gdm` you will see that it installs also gdm, which should not be the case unless 20.04 forcefull installs gdm.

Comment: Please edit your question to include real input and output. Show us the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Xorg without Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256285/installing-xorg-without-gnome) (with some modifications)

Comment: Looks good, I haven't tried this yet though.