# Can I use ubuntu only with a WM, without any DE so less resources are used

Tags: desktop-environments, window-manager

This guy in the [video](https://youtu.be/npR4vHLA890) using gentoo and his system is using only 46mb RAM because he doesn't have any Desktop Environment, he is only using a Window Manager 'DWM'.

I have a very old pc with just 2GB RAM and I use ubuntu on that.
Can I do that thing on Ubuntu.

Comment: The short answer is [you can install `dwm` on a Ubuntu release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dwm). I would not be optimistic about getting memory consumption down to 46MB of RAM, though. There are many reasons for a system to use memory aside from the GUI. That said, what are the hardware specs of the “very old PC”? Depending on what is under the hood, you may be able to use one of the lighter flavours of Ubuntu 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Xorg without Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256285/installing-xorg-without-gnome)

Comment: thanks @matigo and N0rbert, I will try that.